# excel if doesn't match this value match other 3 values

Tags: excel

I woulde like to use if match function to check a value, to see does it exist in three other worksheets.

below is my formula

`=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A1,'sheets2'!$F:$F,0),"yo",
IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B1,'sheets3'!$A:$A,0),"halo",
IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B1,'sheets4'!$G:$G,0),"bye","")))`

however, error occured or can't display correct value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look first at syntax for the combined formula of `IFERROR`, `IF` and `MATCH` you are using:

`= IFERROR( IF( MATCH( A1, 'sheets2'!$F:$F, 0 ), "yo", FALSE ), "!Err" )`

However the `MATCH` function returns an error (`#N/A`) when the value is not found, 
therefore the `IF` function will never return the value assigned to the `FALSE` result, 
as such the syntax to use should be something like this:

`= IFERROR( IF( MATCH( A1, 'sheets2'!$F:$F, 0 ), "yo" ), "!Err" )`

Therefore the syntax required should be something like this *(try this formula)*:

`= IFERROR( IFERROR( IFERROR(
IF( MATCH( A1, Sheets2!$F:$F, 0 ), "yo" ),
IF( MATCH( B1, Sheets3!$A:$A, 0 ), "halo" ) ),
IF( MATCH( B1, Sheets4!$G:$G, 0 ), "bye" ) ), "" )`

Comment: thanks for your answer but it doesn't work. it displays all "halo", no matter it matches or not

Comment: The formula worked in my all tests. 1. Ensure you have copied the formula as presented. 2. Would you please publish a data set with the cases in which its not working so I can fine-tune the formula.

Comment: yea finally find out that i turn off the screen updating and autocaculation, therefore the result will not display correctly!